# UWP on Microsoft Band 2

Tags: uwp, microsoft-band

I'm very interested in developing apps (or rather tiles?) for my Microsoft Band 2.
I'm just wondering if there's any thought of UWP (Universal Windows Platform) on the Band as well?
Currently I'm running an app on my Windows Phone which just writes the current date and time into some csv file on the click of a button.
Now, with my band, it would be much easier to do this little time tracking just right on my wrist too.
But, of course I still want to track the time on my phone and my win10 tablet as well.
The question now .. is it possible to use the "same" app (with different UI on the band ofc) on all these devices (UWP) or do I need some extra app on band to handle this?
The best solution would be "one" app which saves it data into the cloud but I assume that, at least for the band, the data needs to be synced to the phone before then it gets uploaded.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So building applications for the Microsoft Band is unfortunately not using the UWP app model. You'll essentially need to a write an application with UWP for your connected device (Windows PC, Phone etc) and interact with the Band through that application using the Band SDK.

You can create your own tiles which have custom layouts, but as the Band doesn't have any persistent storage as it's intended to be a data tool, you'll have to send the data you're wanting from the Band to the connected device and manipulate from the UWP app there.

Microsoft provide in-depth documentation for developing with the Microsoft Band which you can take a look at here: http://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf

If you're looking to write the application to interact with your phone in the background, you can [take a look at a sample I created](http://jamescroft.co.uk/blog/iot/developing-for-microsoft-band-with-winrt-indefinite-background-execution/) which will do this for you. It was intended for use with the 1st gen Band but as the SDK has been built to work with any Band device, it will work the same way for the Band 2 also.